# Why do I get "TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were give" with my decorator

Tags: python

I am try to use a decorator to do some debugging and learn about decorators and I do not understand why I am getting this error:

```
  File "/Users/red/PycharmProjects/general_purpose_object_factory/music.py", line 26, in __call__
    self._instance = SpotifyService(access_code)
TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code
```

Here is my code:

decorators.py

```
def debug_printer(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Hello")
        func()
    return wrapper
```

music.py

```
import object_factory
from decorators import debug_printer

class MusicServiceProvider(object_factory.ObjectFactory):
    def get(self, service_id, **kwargs):
        return self.create(service_id, **kwargs)

class SpotifyService:
    @debug_printer
    def __init__(self, access_code):
        self._access_code = access_code

    def test_connection(self):
        print(f'Accessing Spotify with {self._access_code}')


class SpotifyServiceBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}")
        self._instance = None

    def __call__(self, spotify_client_key, spotify_client_secret, **_ignored):
        if not self._instance:
            access_code = self.authorize(
                spotify_client_key, spotify_client_secret)
            self._instance = SpotifyService(access_code)  # <<< LINE 26. !!!!!!
        return self._instance

    def authorize(self, key, secret):
        return 'SPOTIFY_ACCESS_CODE'
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What part of `TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given` is unclear? The decorator returns the locally-created `wrapper`; it was defined like `def wrapper():`, so why is it surprising that it doesn't accept any arguments? So, the next question is: *should* it accept arguments? (Yes, because it's decorating something that accepts arguments, and it is expected that the decorated result will be used with the same signature.) Therefore....

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo because it's not clear to me why the logic would be troublesome *for someone who already knows what decorators are and the syntax to write them*. If there's some more specific reason you expected this to work, and existing references such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/ (definitely not a duplicate, but the standard reference material for decorators on Stack Overflow) don't resolve the issue, please try to ask more specifically.

Comment: My usual advice: "what am I doing wrong?"/"why doesn't this work?" etc. is very often the wrong framing. Instead, try to convince us of *why it should* work, and exactly how. (Oh, and I shouldn't have to point an 11-year veteran of the site at this, but please read [mre].)

Comment: WELL EXCUSE ME!

Comment: Sorry you have to deal with the insulting comments @Red Cricket. Despite what Karl says, there's nothing wrong with asking a question when you don't understand something, especially when you state that you're trying to learn about something. And even if similar questions exist, there's no reason for someone to be rude like that.

Answer (score 2):

ok I had to change my decorator to this ...

```
def debug_printer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Calling {func.__qualname__}({args}, {kwargs})")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I still couldn’t get my decorator to work, but I see what you did there.